# How to fix Gradle build error in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:classpath'.
> Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported. Switch Maven repository 'maven2(http://localhost/)' to redirect to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol for more details.

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:classpath'

aused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported. Switch Maven repository 'maven2(http://localhost/)' to redirect to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TgB0.png)

Comment: I think v4.0.1 is way too outdated. Our project is currently in v8.0.1.